# How can I make an InputField with a proper newline/carriage return?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, keyboard, inputfield

The return key does not work as expected in an InputField, how can I overcome this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946475/simple-text-input-field-accepting-line-breaks/

Comment: Also related is this [MathgGroup thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/3a2b1cfa8efa6df9?hl=en#).

Comment: Sure, that might help. I usually search for `is:q keyword` instead of just the title because most users don't always use a good title.

Answer (score 22):

Ah, figured it out:

```
Panel @ DynamicModule[{input = ""}, 
  Column[{TextCell["Enter your text here:"], 
    EventHandler[
     InputField[Dynamic[input], String, ContinuousAction -> True, 
      FieldSize -> {40, 7}], 
     "ReturnKeyDown" :> 
      FrontEndExecute[{NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "\n", After]}]
     ], Dynamic@InputForm[input]}]]
```

Comment: On a related note: I wonder if that could also be used to intercept "Shift-return" - but I doubt it...

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in version 7.

Comment: This solves a long standing question of mine, so thanks! I made an edit for it to handle Shift-Return:
`EventHandler[
 InputField[Dynamic[demo2], String, FieldHint -> "Quarter 1 Turnover",
   Alignment -> {Left, Center}], {{"MenuCommand", 
    "HandleShiftReturn"} :> 
   FrontEndExecute[{NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "\n", After]}], 
  "ReturnKeyDown" :> 
   FrontEndExecute[{NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "\n", After]}]}]`

Comment: Doesn't work in the cloud.

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps something like this?

```
text = "";
EventHandler[
 InputField[Dynamic@text, String, ContinuousAction -> True],
 {"ReturnKeyDown" :> Paste["\n"]}
 ]
```

Comment: Cool!.. Tks I'll wait to accept just to follow the protocols. :)

Comment: Doesn't work in the cloud.

Comment: @M.R. Maybe tell it to WRI?  I'm not sure there's a real Front End in the Cloud. I told a developer in passing about some glitch a year ago at the 2019 tech conf, and they put me in contact with the lead developer right away.  He seemed to realize there were some issues, but they seemed to want to make it work.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a widget which I constructed some time ago for my purposes. This is an `InputField` as well, but it operates on boxes, and as a bonus, the standard syntax highlighting works inside it:

```
ClearAll[codeInputField];
Attributes[codeInputField] = {HoldFirst}; 
Options[codeInputField] = {
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontWeight -> Plain, FontFamily -> "Courier"},
   FieldSize -> {20, {2, Infinity}},
   ImageSize -> Automatic, 
   KeyEventActions -> Automatic,
   EnterPressedCustomFunction :> Automatic
};

codeInputField[startingCode_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  With[{bs = OptionValue[BaseStyle], fsize = OptionValue[FieldSize], 
    acts = OptionValue[KeyEventActions],
    EnterPressedF = OptionValue[EnterPressedCustomFunction], 
    ims = OptionValue[ImageSize]},
   Module[{nb, enterPressed},
     With[{actions = 
       Sequence @@ 
        If[acts === Automatic,
          {},
          Replace[acts, 
           (s_ -> f_) :> (s :> f[Hold[startingCode], Hold[enterPressed], s, nb]),
           {1}]
        ],
        enterF  = If[EnterPressedF === Automatic, Hold, EnterPressedF]
      },
     EventHandler[
       InputField[
          Dynamic[
             startingCode, 
             (nb = InputNotebook[]; startingCode = #) &
          ],
          Boxes, 
          FieldSize -> fsize, ContinuousAction -> True, 
          BaseStyle -> bs, ImageSize -> ims
       ],
       {"ReturnKeyDown" :>
          (
              enterPressed = True;
              enterF[Hold[startingCode], nb];
              FrontEndExecute[NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "\n"]];
              If[! ValueQ[nb], nb = InputNotebook[]];
              SetOptions[NotebookSelection[nb], ShowSelection -> True]; 
          ),
          actions
       },
       PassEventsDown -> True
  ]]]];
```

Here is an example of use:

```
code = MakeBoxes[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}]];
Dynamic[code]
```

> ```
>  RowBox[{"Plot","[",RowBox[{RowBox[{"Sin","[","x","]"}],",",RowBox[{" 
>      {",RowBox[{"x",",","0",",",RowBox[{"4"," ","\[Pi]"}]}],"}"}]}],"]"}]
> ```

The above dynamic is to monitor the `code` variable. Now, the input field:

```
codeInputField[code]
```

[image]

The highlighting is enabled after "Enter"  is pressed the first time. You can edit the code to see the highlighting at work and how the `code` variable is updated.

I also coded an interactive REPL-style cell based on this, which can evaluate code inside it. If there is an interest in it, I could expand to include that as well.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just checked, and it works for me, M7.0, Win7 64 bit. What exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: The first time I tried it *Mathematica* crashed.  This time it worked.  Still if I press numeric-keypad Return in the input field it crashes.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Interesting. Numeric-keypad Return does not crash it for me, but creates a new cell, instead of just do a carriage return.

Comment: Doesn't work in the cloud.

Comment: @M.R. Was never supposed to.

Comment: Is anything supposed to work in the cloud?

Comment: @M.R. Can't tell. I find the design of the cloud (as little as I know about it) very different from what I'd like it to be or what I'd have done if I was tasked to design it. May be there were good reasons to do it the way it was done, that I simply don't understand.

Answer (score 5):

This dialog box version was put together some time ago for *Mathematica* 7 :-

```
text = "";
DialogInput[{TextCell["Try to type a text with linebreaks :-)"], 
  InputField[Dynamic[text], String, FieldSize -> {30, 6}], 
  DefaultButton[DialogReturn[text]]}, 
 NotebookEventActions -> {"ReturnKeyDown" :> 
    FrontEndExecute[NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "\n"]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work in the cloud.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that an **undocumented** `InputFieldBoxOptions -> {"ReturnEntersInput" -> False}` does this:

```
InputField[
  Dynamic[x], String
, BaseStyle -> InputFieldBoxOptions -> {"ReturnEntersInput" -> False}
]
```

It does not help with numpad <kbd>Enter</kbd> which can accidentally evaluate the cell. But that is the case with other answers too so the full answer is:

```
EventHandler[
  InputField[Dynamic[x], String
  , BaseStyle -> InputFieldBoxOptions -> {"ReturnEntersInput" -> False}
  ]
, {"MenuCommand", "EvaluateCells"} :> Paste["\n"]
]
```

Comment: Doesn't work in the cloud.

Comment: @M.R. not surprised :(

Answer (score 2):

In version 13.2, I just typed `Options[InputField]` and found an undocumented option named `ReturnEntersInput`. Well... it works. This must by my shortest answer ever:

```
InputField[Dynamic[text], String, ReturnEntersInput -> False,  FieldSize -> {30, 10}]
```

I wonder when was this option added. It is undocumented, but it is not displayed in red by the front end.

Comment: This crashes in the cloud