# In InputField, how to prevent Shift-Return from generating a new cell?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, undocumented

When running the following in a notebook (not a deployed `CDF` file), it can sometimes be annoying that accidentally pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Return</kbd> breaks out of the user interface:

```
Panel@DynamicModule[{input = ""}, InputField[Dynamic[input], String]]
```

I would like to know if one can (programmatically) prevent such a cell from being "evaluated" when <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Return</kbd> is pressed, so that the user stays in the `InputField` instead of being thrown out of it while seeing a new generated cell appear.

Comment: One quick hack is to define a custom evaluator for the cell in which the `InputField` is, and make it return `Null` at the end. You can test by setting it to a simple `CellEvaluationFunction->(Null& )`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I tried that, and it's very close because it doesn't generate a new cell. But it still evaluates silently, increases the history counter and puts the cursor in the next line.

Comment: No time to do this myself, but one idea is examining the help browser's docked cell which also has an InputField in it.

Comment: @Szabolcs  That sounds like a good idea. Get help from the help browser in an unconventional way...

Comment: @Jens I briefly looked at it and it seems to be defined as a "front end resource" (not sure what that is).  The next step would be searching the installation files for this resource (e.g. even the Find window is a notebook that you can examine---and yes, that has an input field too, maybe we don't need to go to the help browser!) ... Okay, I got to sleep now, I need to catch the Venus transit tomorrow at dawn :-)

Comment: Now, all these solutions seem to work for shift+enter but not for my small enter on the number pad... Hummm

Comment: Found it. What you want is to set `Deployed->True` in the output cell

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you notice *Mathematica* Documentation Center search field is kind of the same thing. And search window from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> too. It uses a similar concept to what I'll show. Important thing to know is that `EventHandler` can track commands from the *Mathematica* menu. There is an undocumented option `HandleShiftReturn` and here is a trick I learned from FW:

```
DynamicModule[{x = ""}, 
  Column[{
    EventHandler[
      InputField[Dynamic[x], String], 
      {{"MenuCommand", "HandleShiftReturn"} :> {},
       {"MenuCommand", "EvaluateCells"} :> {}} (*edit by Kuba, handles Keypad Enter*)
    ], 
    Dynamic[x]
   }]
]
```

[image]

<kbd>Return</kbd> works, but <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Return</kbd> does not.

Comment: Ah, finally: I had been trying to guess what the Menu command for "Evaluate Cells" might be and gave up guessing a while ago...

Comment: users could be saved a lot of time if all this stuff was documented.

Comment: @Vitaliy could you please add whatever you know about events for `EventHandler` as an answer to this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6207/how-do-i-find-all-the-possible-events-that-work-with-eventhandler. thanks

Comment: This also catches Shift+Return but not keypad Return.  Is there a way to extend it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard add `{"MenuCommand", "EvaluateCells"}` event handler, [47513](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47513/5478)

Comment: @Jens "EvaluateCells" is in fact a valid token but responsible for keypad Enter.

Comment: @Kuba Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

```
ExpressionCell[Panel@DynamicModule[{input = ""}, InputField[Dynamic[input], String]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
Content added:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd> pressed:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Learned this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250623/615464).

Comment: It works! I also combined it with [Mike's answer to a related issue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6458/245) and it still worked in that more complicated setting, too.

Comment: @jens Glad to hear. I still find `ExpressionCell` a somewhat mysterious function.

Comment: This catches Shift+Return but not keypad Return.  Any comment on that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry, I'm on a laptop without keypad. Can't test.

Answer (score 7):

This is just adding a `Deployed->True` to your output cell, and removing the `CellEditDuplicate` which ruins everything

```
CellPrint@
  ExpressionCell[
   Panel@DynamicModule[{input = ""}, 
     InputField[Dynamic[input], String]], "Output",  
   CellEditDuplicate -> False, Deployed -> True];
```

Actually, with `CellEditDuplicate->False` should be enough. However, keep `Deployed` in mind if you use other styles, and so `Evaluatable->False`

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be an **undocumented** `InputBoxOptions` `"TrapEnterKey"` which does just that:

```
InputField[
  Dynamic[x]
, String
, BaseStyle -> InputFieldBoxOptions -> {"TrapEnterKey" -> True}
]
```