# Wrapping at evaluation for inline cell

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, keyboard, customization

I've been playing with inline evaluation and I've came to the conclusion that it's most convenient to put the `Dynamic@` inside the inline cell, so I've started to search for a way to omit typing it altogether. I've tried using `CellEvaluationFunction` and `CellProlog`, but with no luck.
How can I achieve this?

Also, it would be best if the wrapping with `Dynamic[]` occurred only in inline cell evaluations (which happen in ordinary text cells)

Comment: Well, that seems like a good enough solution. I mean I could do an input alias with a placeholder and set the focus to the placeholder. Why is Dynamic such a bad thing? I mean, beside the irritating information when I open the document it seems to work fine... 

Different, but related problem is how to evaluate an inline cell without having to select it first (even though I can do it with keyboard)

Comment: Not a big problem but each Dynamic cell uses part of processor. Is my answer ok?

Comment: It's perfect, thanks :) You're also right about the CPU, drains the battery waaay faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add this piece of code and use it instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> for you own inline cell:

```
Item[KeyEvent["t", Modifiers -> {Control}],
     FrontEndExecute[
        FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[
          FrontEnd`InputNotebook[],
            Cell[ BoxData[ RowBox[{"Dynamic", "[", "\[Placeholder]", "]"}] ], 
                 CellEventActions -> {{"MenuCommand", "HandleShiftReturn"} :> {
                      SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, CellContents];   
                      SelectionEvaluate[EvaluationNotebook[]]}}
                ]
        ];
        FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], Previous, Character, 2];
        FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], All, Character]
    ]
   ]
```

- Now with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, or whatever you want that is free, you will create a cell with `Dynamic` already written.
- Also <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> results in evaluation in place without selecting it.

#### Edit:

If you want numeric keypad <kbd>Enter</kbd> to do this **`Evaluation In Place`** you can use `{"MenuCommand", "EvaluateCells"}` event instead of `"HandleShiftReturn"`. For me it would be great since I hardly ever use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### Ref:

Here is a tutorial how to add a new shortcut: [Automating Esc [[ Esc formatting?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5212/5478)

Here is a reference [link about how to catch <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6459/5478)

Comment: Works great, thanks! The only thing is that the focus doesn't move to the placeholder after insertion, but I can live with that.

Comment: I'm not sure why you've removed the closing bracket - it works the same way with it. It's much better but I still need to make a some keystrokes (move selection to the left and then Tab). Thanks, for helping me out so much!

Comment: Works flawlessly now! You sir are awesome!

Comment: @Ranza Great, good luck :)

Comment: Of course I'm interested!

Comment: @Ranza So, it's in the Edit:) I'm not sure if I pointed it well. Tell me if this works for you.

Comment: Can't really test it cause currently on the laptop, but it's nice to know that it's possible! thanks.

Comment: It looks like selection of inline cell with `SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], All, CellContents];` is broken in MMA10

Comment: @Ranza I;ve just installed v10 and this command works so far, are you sure it is about this line? I have not tested whole code in v10 yet.

Comment: It seems to select the parent cell as well as the inline cell on my machine, I've tried using Expression and Word parameters, but although it selected it properly it didn't evaluate them the way it should; converting Dynamic[x] expression to Dynamic[x] string.

Comment: @Ranza I will take a closer look tomorrow, sorry for the delay.