# Off printing plots in manipulate

Tags: manipulate, printing

This is very simple question. On the Manipulate control screen, if I set the parameter and hit "Enter", it will produce some plot under the manipulation. Can I shut off the printing even if I enter the parameter?

Comment: Try the `TrackedSymbols` option.

Comment: You can just ignore pressing enter, if you type in the values and deselect the input box the changes should get applied.

Comment: You mean Keypad Enter?

Comment: You can use an `EventHandler`, over your whole `Manipulate`, shown in the accepted answer in: [How to prevent Shift-Return from generating a new cell?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6459/5478)

Comment: @kuba Thank you!