# Enter text with newlines in Inputfield

Tags: notebooks, inputfield

With `InputField` we can enter strings or numbers etc.
I would like to input a piece of text including newlines, tabs etc.
How can I do this? With standard:

```
InputField[Dynamic[str],String]
```

The Enter (newline) is not added to the string. Any other way to let a user
type some text including newlines, tabs etc?

Comment: closely related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6459/5478

Comment: @Lou not too elaborated but `InputField[Dynamic[str]]"`and introducing "Hello\nHello\tHello" (with the " " included), returns to str a string with a newline (\n) and a tab in the second line (\t)...

Comment: .. I searched to find an answer before I posted.. Thanks @Kuba the solution is great.