# InputField always generate new object after pressing Enter

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

I am using Mathematica 11.2. There seems something wrong with InputField.

As you can see from below gif animation. Every time I change the InputField and press enter, new object generated. This nonsense. What is wrong? Is there a work around?

[image]

Comment: Enter or NumPad Enter?

Comment: Hi, @Kuba Thank you so much ! You really get the point! It is the NumPad Enter issue

Comment: See this: [6466](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6466/5478), you can wrap whole Manipulate

Comment: @Kuba Frankly, I didn't get the point of that post. Could you post an answer on how to handle both enter and numpad enter? Anyway, is this intended behaviour? Why enter is not the same as numpad enter?

Comment: This seems too close for a separate answer: `EventHandler[ Manipulate[  x, {x, 1}], {{"MenuCommand", "EvaluateCells"} :> {}, {"MenuCommand",
     "HandleShiftReturn"} :> {}}]` they behave in a slightly different way.

Comment: @Kuba Great, this works. But one more question. Why “HandleShiftReturn“？ I thought we were talking about Numpad enter here? Do they related?

Comment: Just in case you hit it :) NumPad Enter evaluates cells yet you've hit it.

Comment: @Kuba You are right. Numpad enter's behaviour seems equivalent to shift+enter in mathematica