# How to set up the Enter, Shift+Enter feature in InputField?

Tags: inputfield

When InputField was set to String, I found a way to change the line of the sentence by pressing Enter.
In this case, how does the calculation run when the Shift+Enter key is pressed?

```
EventHandler[ InputField[Dynamic@text, String, ContinuousAction -> True, 
              ImageSize -> {300, 100}], {"ReturnKeyDown" :> Paste["\n"]}]
```

[image]

I want to write a few lines of instruction in the InputField and run it when I press Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining your attempt with the technique from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6459/in-inputfield-how-to-prevent-shift-return-from-generating-a-new-cell):

```
multilineInput[Dynamic[text_]] := DynamicModule[
  {innerText = If[StringQ@text, text, ""]},
  EventHandler[
   InputField[Dynamic@innerText, String],
   {
    "ReturnKeyDown" :> If[! CurrentValue["ShiftKey"], Paste["\n"]],
    {"MenuCommand", 
      "HandleShiftReturn"} :> {text = innerText}, {"MenuCommand", 
      "EvaluateCells"} :> {text = innerText}
    },
   PassEventsDown -> False
   ]
  ]

text = "Hello world";
multilineInput[Dynamic@text]
Dynamic@text
```

[image]

Comment: It's great!
It was a great help! Thank you~^^