# Updating a tracked symbol inside Refresh?

Tags: dynamic, evaluation, manipulate

I have some code inside a `Manipulate`, whose goal is to allow the user to edit the upper half of the matrix while keeping it symmetric at all time. The minimal code is the following:

```
Manipulate[
 Refresh[
    i = i + 1;
    Do[Cmat[[i, j]] = Cmat[[j, i]], {i, 2, 6}, {j, 1, i - 1}];
  , TrackedSymbols -> {Cmat}];
 {i, Grid[Array[InputField[Dynamic[Cmat[[#1, #2]]], FieldSize -> 5, Enabled -> #1 <= #2] &, {6, 6}]]}
 ,
 Initialization :> (
   i = 0;
   Cmat = ConstantArray[0, {6, 6}];
   )]
```

I added the `i` variable as a counter, and I expected it to be only incremented when I actually change the value of one of the `Cmat` elements. What actually happens is that `i` increases near the speed of the runloop, and that code actually hogs the CPU (one core of it, anyway). I suppose what happens is that the modification of the tracked value inside `Refresh` actually triggers `Refresh` itself, hence the loop.

How can I prevent this? I thought restricting `TrackedSymbols` to the upper half of `Cmat` would do the trick, but it changes nothing. Is there a way, inside of `Refresh`, to change `Cmat` without it being tracked? The opposition functionality exists, in the form of `Update`.

Answer (score 4):

Why Refresh? The second argument of Dynamic is your friend:

```
DynamicModule[
  {Cmat = ConstantArray[0, {6, 6}]}, 
 Deploy@Panel@Grid[Array[Function[{m, n}, 
      InputField[Dynamic[Cmat[[m,n]], 
        (Cmat[[m,n]] = #1; 
          Cmat[[n,m]] = #1) & ], 
       Number, FieldSize -> 5, 
       Enabled -> m <= n, 
       ContinuousAction -> True]], 
     {6, 6}]]]
```

Comment: Yes, I can do it like that, I forgot about it… I like the `Refresh` construct, though, and I'd like even better to understand how to make it work. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you say `Update` has the opposite functionality? Perhaps what you want is something like this, changing your code minimally

```
Manipulate[Refresh[i = i + 1;
  Do[Cmat[[i, j]] = Cmat[[j, i]], {i, 2, 6}, {j, 1, i - 1}];, 
  None]; Cmat;
 {i, Grid[
   Array[InputField[Dynamic[Cmat[[#1, #2]]], FieldSize -> 5, 
      Enabled -> #1 <= #2] &, {6, 6}]]}, Initialization :> (i = 0;
   Cmat = ConstantArray[0, {6, 6}];)]
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. If you switch focus out and back in the matrix, your counter starts to increment like crazy!

Comment: @F'x I'm trying to reproduce that but so far I couldn't!

Comment: This works fine as long as I don't hit the [enter] key after entering a value (as one is tempted to do when entering digits from the numeric keypad). At least on my system, I get two copies of the panel and a runaway counter if I hit [enter] as opposed to [return].

Comment: @m_goldberg, I think that issue has it's own question already. You don't get that problem when hitting enter with the original solution?

Comment: @Rojo: I didn't mean to imply that the problem was peculiar to your answer. It is more general -- it seems occur with most if not all dynamic output cells. Can you give me a link to where this has been discussed before? I'd be interested in reading that discussion.

Comment: @m_goldberg probably [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6457/109) is what I had in mind

Comment: @Rojo. I read the discussion you pointed me to. What Mr.Wizard experienced is similar and maybe the same as what I mentioned.