# Make Enter create new line break inside InputField

Tags: inputfield, interface

I would like to write multiple lines of text inside an `InputField`, using `ContinuousAction->True` to update some variable `x` (so I don't need <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

```
InputField[Dynamic[x], String, ContinuousAction -> True]
```

[image]

To do the above image, I have to copy and past the text.

The point is, if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the standard behavior is to try to update `x` value.
How can I change it in order to make <kbd>Enter</kbd> to create a new line break in the text inside the `InputField` instead of try to evaluate it?

Comment: @rm-rf Should we change `InputField[]` into `InputField` in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6457)? If I look for title:InputField (that was how I look for similar), I can find this question!