# InputField with carriage return in cloud notebooks?

Tags: notebooks, gui-construction, wolfram-cloud, inputfield

I'm looking for a way of constructing a multi-line `InputField` in a cloud notebook. That is, a text field that supports the following five behaviors:

1. **The 'Enter' key should make a new line**
2. **Anywhere you click within it, the `InputField` will begin editing**
3. Anywhere you mouseover the `InputField`, the mouse changes to a cursor
4. The 'Tab' key should make a new tab indent
5. The `InputField` rectangle should be resizeable

Is there any workaround to get *at least the first two desired properties* above in a cloud notebook?

**What I've tried:**

In (desktop) Mathematica, you can hack around `InputField` to get the newline-return behavior as described in this post:

- [How can I make an InputField with a proper newline/carriage return?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6457/how-can-i-make-an-inputfield-with-a-proper-newline-carriage-return)

For example, here's one way to do it:

```
text = ""; EventHandler[
    InputField[ Dynamic @ text, String, ContinuousAction -> True, ImageSize->{300,100}],
    {"ReturnKeyDown" :> Paste["\n"]}
]
```

I have tried all of the workarounds in the link, and each one fails in a Cloud notebook.

Comment: A workaround I have found for point (2) is to add a FieldHint, for example `InputField["", String, ImageSize -> {450, 350}, FieldHint -> StringRiffle[Table[".",3000],"  "]]` -- but this only works when you have no content in the input field yet.

Comment: I would rather not have dots everywhere in my text field...

Comment: Neither would I :) It's not pretty but it kind of sort of works...

Comment: That is not a solution

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to do with an HTML `textarea`. The following takes care of the TAB issue.

```
html = "<textarea id=\"test\" name=\"myTest\" rows=\"3\" cols=\"30\" \
onkeydown='var key = event.keyCode;if (key==9) \
{event.preventDefault();str=this.selectionStart;end=this.selectionEnd;\
this.value = this.value.substring(0,str) + \"\\t\" + \
this.value.substring(end);this.selectionStart =
        this.selectionEnd = start + 1;}'></textarea>";
```

The html can be embedded in a cloud [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/4fab1d62-75f1-4a5a-9c2c-9d18e750be62). The minimum size of the textarea is set in the html, but is resizable to a larger size. However the cell containing the textarea does not seem to resize to a larger size.

```
CloudDeploy[EmbeddedHTML[html], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

Another option is to export the [textarea html](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/3cf7e272-8fca-4487-9b51-3debd042c939).

```
CloudDeploy[ExportForm[html, "HTML"], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, more of a funny bug in the Cloud (and a sign of how hard this may be)

[image]

You might be best off writing your functions to post-process data in a regular-schmegular `Cell`